# Dynamic reference in Firebase through a react native application

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data from Firebase database in my react native application. The data is structured like the image. My purpose is to extract the food list from each item in the list.

I tried this line but it's not working:

```
this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('menu/item'+{$id}+'/no');
```

it keeps telling me that it {$id } is unknown. And i know i need to put id in an interval and then make a foreach function, but I don't know how to do it

PS: in my console it appears that food : undefined and I got a scrolling list view in my screen

So, what should I put instead? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please add more code. Where/how is $id being used?

Comment: actually, i know i have to use $id that must be a number in [0..87].. but i don't know how to do it ..